# Custom markers on an Orthographic Projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, orthographic

I am using this approach to draw points on a Map with a Orthographic projection:

```
    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(…)
        .pointRadius(function(d) { return d.radius; });

    svg.selectAll("path.point")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("path")
        .datum(function(d) {
           return {type: "Point", coordinates: [d.Lon, d.Lat], radius: d.Magnitude};
        })
        .attr("class", "point")
        .attr("d", path);
```

This works well.

What can be done to make these points appear as **triangles** instead of circles?

Comment: This isn't supported out of the box by D3. You'll have to create the triangle shapes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use d3.svg.symbol().

```
    //define triangle
var arc = d3.svg.symbol().type('triangle-up');

    // put a triangle on every city
svg.selectAll(".tripath")
    .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.places).features)
 .enter().append("path")
    .attr('d',arc)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; });
```

There are some predefined symbols:

```
circle - a circle.
cross - a Greek cross or plus sign.
diamond - a rhombus.
square - an axis-aligned square.
triangle-down - a downward-pointing equilateral triangle.
triangle-up - an upward-pointing equilateral triangle.
```

Here you have Mike's Wiki: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#symbol

And here you can see a working code: http://jsfiddle.net/6d3ansfn/

Comment: Thanks @Klaujesi. This is a good solution. But I was hoping to use a path geometry object so that any necessary path redraw ( panning or projection transitions) would account for this symbol. I ended up constructing a triangularly shaped polygon based on coordinate information

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for generating triangle-markers using a path geometry object. The two initial coordinates as center points for each triangle.

```
let halfWidth = 0.15;

points.enter().append('path')
  .datum((d) => {
    let pointA = [(Number(d.coord[0]) - halfWidth).toString(), (Number(d.coord[1]) - halfWidth).toString()];
    let pointB = [d.coord[0], (Number(d.coord[1]) + halfWidth).toString()];
    let pointC = [(Number(d.coord[0]) + halfWidth).toString(), (Number(d.coord[1]) - halfWidth).toString()];

    polypoints = [
      [pointA, pointB, pointC, pointA]
    ];

    return {
      type: 'Polygon',
      coordinates: polypoints,
      id: d.id,
      center: d.coord,
    };
  });
```